# How to fetch data from three firebase collections into one table in react.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have three different collections in cloud firestore and I am storing my feedback app data in these collections. In the beginning I am storing students data into the students collection, after that I am storing the feedback of the student inside feedback collection and finally I am storing some extra information inside the details collections. Now I am fetching all the data in my admin panel table. I have fetched the details collection data successfully but not getting the logic of how get other informations in the table, and how will I relate the data with each other?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import AdminNavbar from '../../layout/AdminNavbar';
import firebase from '../../../config/fbConfig';

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  const [tableData, settableData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    getdata();
  });

  console.log(props);
  async function getdata() {
     const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("details");
    const snapshot = await ref.get();
    settableData(snapshot.docs.map(doc=>doc.data()))     
  }

  const tableCol = [
    {
      title: "Course expectations",
      field: "course_delivering_on_your_expectations"
    },
    {
      title: "Oppurtunities",
      field: "enough_opportunities_to_apply"
    },
    {
      title: "Explanation Clear",
      field: "explanation_of_concepts_clear"
    },
    {
      title: "Knowledge",
      field: "instructor_knowledgeable_about_the_topics"
    },
    {
      title: "Engaging",
      field: "instructors_delivery_engaging"
    },
    {
      title: "Learning",
      field: "learning_valuable_information"
    }
  ];
  
    return (
        <>
            <AdminNavbar />
            <div className="table-div">
                <MaterialTable
          title={"Student's Feedback"}
            data={tableData}
          columns={tableCol}
          
          options={{
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "#01579b",
              color: "#FFF"
            },
            exportButton: true,
            selection: false,
            search: true
          }}
          
        />
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for fetching 3 collections at the same time in a single query because Firestore queries are shallow.

You can use [collection groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection_group) to achieve your goal. If the collections have different IDs, you would need multiple reads and join them client side.